# Poincaré conjecture on infinite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a path-connected infinite-dimensional separable Banach manifold without boundary. If $M$ has trivial homotopy groups for every finite dimension $n$, is $M$ necessarily homeomorphic to the standard separable Hilbert space $l^2$? I have recently known that every infinite-dimensional separable Banach space is homeomorphic to each other (and thus homeomorphic to $l^2$), and the unit sphere in $l^2$ is homeomorphic to $l^2$ itself. However, as every infinite dimensional Banach space is indeed of uncountably infinite dimension as a vector space, a number of structures seem to be ignored only considering the countably many homotopy groups. I tend to believe my question has a negative answer and I seek a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. I recommend to have a look into

> Bessaga, C., & Pełczyński, A. (1975). Selected topics in infinite-dimensional topology (Vol. 58). PWN-Polish Scientific Publishers.

In Chapter IX the authors consider infinite-dimensional manifolds whose model is a linear metric space.

In Theorem IX.1.3 they prove that every manifold $M$ modeled on a locally convex linear metric space $Y$ is an ANR. Since each ANR has the homotopy type of a CW-complex, the vanishing of all homotopy groups of $M$ implies that $M$ is contractible.

In Theorem IX.7.3 they prove that $Y$-manifolds have the same homotopy type iff they are homeomorphic *provided* $Y$ is a locally convex linear metric space such that $Y \approx Y^{\mathbb N}$. Hence for such $Y$ a contractible $Y$-manifold is homeomorphic to $Y$. Note that all infinite dimensional separable Banach spaces have this property (see Chapter VI §5).

Comment: What $Y$'s satisfy $Y \simeq Y^{\Bbb{N}}$ in general?

Comment: See my update .